# Discord.py Reactions

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, bots

My discord.py bot adds the role and emoji to the name when I react to the embed, but it doesn't remove the role and emoji when I remove the reaction.

My script:

```
# Event when the user reacts to a message
@bot.event
async def on_reaction_add(reaction, user):
  if user.bot:
    return

  emoji = reaction.emoji
  if emoji in emojis:
    index = emojis.index(emoji)
    guild = reaction.message.guild
    cargo = nextcord.utils.get(guild.roles, name=cargos[index])

    if cargo:
      await user.add_roles(cargo)
      apelido_atual = user.display_name

      # Verifique se o emoji já está no apelido
      if emoji not in apelido_atual:
        novo_apelido = f'{apelido_atual} {emoji}'  # Adicione o emoji ao apelido atual
        try:
          await user.edit(nick=novo_apelido)
        except nextcord.errors.Forbidden:
          print(f'Não foi possível alterar o apelido de {user.display_name}')


# Event when the user removes the reaction from a message
@bot.event
async def on_raw_reaction_remove(payload):
  emoji = payload.emoji.name
  if emoji in emojis:
    index = emojis.index(emoji)
    guild = bot.get_guild(payload.guild_id)
    cargo = nextcord.utils.get(guild.roles, name=cargos[index])
    user = guild.get_member(payload.user_id)

    if cargo and user:
      await user.remove_roles(cargo)
      apelido_atual = user.display_name
      novo_apelido = apelido_atual.replace(f' {emoji}', '')

      try:
        await user.edit(nick=novo_apelido)
      except nextcord.errors.Forbidden:
        print(f'Não foi possível alterar o apelido de {user.display_name}')


bot.run(TOKEN)
```

I tried to make the bot remove the role when I remove the reaction from the message, as expected it adds the role when I react, but it is not removing the role when I remove my reaction.

Comment: You need the members intent to get reaction removed events